# Boost Asio J1939 / Can-bus Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost-asio, can-bus

I am implementing a J1939 socket handler on top of Boost::ASIO and [canary](https://github.com/djarek/canary). My previous application had a socket to listen for devices and the each device discovered would also have a socket. Each socket would use the same interface (In this case can0). From my understanding of [SocketCan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/networking/can.html#) and [J1939](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/j1939.html) this is the correct approach. As each socket can have filters applied to only get messages from the device its listening for.

In my current application I have tested `async_read` on two sockets with two threads executing `io_context.run()`. From the logs this seems to be perfectly fine. I am guessing that this is because the kernel checks against the filters on each socket before passing the data on. However with `async_write` I am a lot more uncertain about thread safety.

Given that all the sockets have the same interface (can0) would the sockets need to share a strand? Or is a strand in each socket handler enough? Or is there is there some synchronization in the kernel that means writing to the CAN-bus is thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is synchronization in the kernel. The same happens for example with TCP sockets. They also share a single network interface (like eth0). The linux network subsystem makes sure, that different sockets (used by different threads or even processes) can share one interface without colliding. You only need synchronization if you access one socket from several threads simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. With that in mind I will use a ASIO Strand to wrap the {async_write} to make it synchronous. Have seen other examples that also do this with TCP. Was just uncertain if it also applied to CAN networks.